# Loading plugin's in new AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, appdomain

I know the there is plenty of threads about loading plugins in new app domain. My fault I didn't read them before.. I have this school project - plugin based app, which is almost done. Except one important point - plugins has to be loaded in new domain..
I create plugin based app using this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6334/Plug-ins-in-C

I'm currently in time press with project deadline and i'm stucked with plugin in same application domain. 
could you please advice me if it's possible to do some simple changes to application in link to load plugins in separate app domain? I really dont wont to write the app from start. :(

Thank you for all your advices.

Comment: working on last hours...aaah school :)

Comment: Before Assembly pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(FileName);
Create a new AppDomain : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173140(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Guys, thank you for answers, I see that I'll have to use System.AddIn probably, however is there way to pass UserControl over System.AddIn?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("domain name");

// TODO: configure appdomain as needed

// to load the dll and get a type you can reference in your current appdomain
string pathToDll = @"C:\somedir\Mydll.dll";
Type myType = typeof(SomeType);
SomeType myObj = (SomeType)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, myType.FullName);


// to just load the dll into the new appdomain
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToDll);
domain.Load(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

I once tried to divide my WinForms application into separate AppDomains and it wasn't easy at all. However, in your case it should not be very difficult.

Try to create a new AppDomain and load your plug-in type in it. Then communicate with that object using reflection or a common base interface (remeber that you cannot reference the plug-in type in your host application if you want to avoid loading the plugin assembly into the host AppDomain).

You might also want to look at the [System.AddIn namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.aspx) - it was implemented specifically to make plugin development easy.

Comment: Thank you Marek, System.AddIn look great hovewer it seems like recode at least half of the app if I understand it well.. I have to create Contracts, HostView etc... but i dont know how to take use contracts etc.. for UserControl:(

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Addin.
Take a look at this sample (or others from this CodePlex page)

http://clraddins.codeplex.com/releases/view/9454